# Function Argument displays value but the Cell is NA

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match

I have a function that looks like this

```
=INDEX(ListShipping!$A:$AS;MATCH(1;(C$5+$A12=ListShipping!$AK:$AK)*("ld"=ListShipping!$AM:$AM);0);45)
```

When I look at my fonction I see the desired valued

[image]

but in the cell I get a "#N/A" value

I also validated that...

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Did you confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter?  This is an array formula and as such depending on your version one may need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Hello Scott, Thanks... This did the job.